# SQL CE: Select distinct, order by another column

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

I'm trying to figure out how to order my data that I get, I want to do a select distinct(name) and order by ID like this:

```
var querythis = "SELECT distinct(exerVariName) as variants FROM Test WHERE date = @0 ORDER BY ID";
```

So I somehow have to select distinct(id) as well, is this possible to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select exerVariName as variants,
    MIN(ID) as min_id
from Test
where date = @0
group by exerVariName
order by min_id
```

Comment: Excellent! Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

You can't order by a column which is not in your select list when using DISTINCT.

But you get also get a distinct result using GROUP BY:

```
SELECT exerVariName as variants 
FROM Test 
WHERE date = @0 
GROUP BY exerVariName
ORDER BY MIN(ID) -- or MAX(ID)
```

Edit:

If CE doesn't allow aggregate functions in ORDER BY you might try a Derived Table (hopefully it's allowed):

```
SELECT variants 
FROM 
 ( 
    SELECT exerVariName as variants, MIN(ID) as minID -- or MAX(ID)
    FROM Test 
    WHERE date = @0 
    GROUP BY exerVariName
 ) AS dt
ORDER BY minID
```

Comment: `Expressions in the ORDER BY list cannot contain aggregate functions.` It gave me this error :/